# Packaging values in DWORD

Tags: c++, windows, bit-manipulation

How would I package two `unsigned short` (`WORD`) values into one `unsigned long` (`DWORD`) value?

I know how to get them using `HIWORD` and `LOWORD` macros but is there a ... sort of reverse macro for storing them into a `DWORD` quickly?

I'm programming in C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 IDE.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`MAKELONG`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes two `WORD`s and combines them into a single `DWORD`:

```
DWORD MAKELONG(
  WORD wLow,
  WORD wHigh
);
```

No idea why it isn't called `MAKEDWORD`...

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
 DWORD x = (lo) | (hi << 16);
```

should do it.

Comment: Thanks also. This answers gives me an idea of what actually goes on behind the scenes. But I've marked the MAKELONG macro as the answer because it is shorter to write. :) +1 though.

Comment: Yes, that's the official method, I'd say.

Answer (score 2):

What about this [MAKELONG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632660%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) macro?

```
DWORD MAKELONG(
  WORD wLow,
  WORD wHigh
);
```